# Color stored in CoreData not equal to original color when retrieved

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am storing a color in Core Data, in my object class I have:

```
@NSManaged public var colorData: Data?

func getColor() -> Color {
    guard let colorData = colorData else { return .clear }

    do {
        return try Color(NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData) ?? .clear)
    } catch {
        print("Error getting color")
    }

    return .clear
}
```

I set the color as follows:

```
do {
    try habit.colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
        withRootObject: UIColor(color), requiringSecureCoding: false)
} catch {
    print("Error setting habit color data")
}
```

Visually this works fine. However if I save a color such as `Color.blue`, retrieve it and then check `color == Color.blue` I get `false`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You are converting Color to UIColor and back. Of course it's not going to be the same constant. For example try `let colorA = Color.blue; 
let uiColorA = UIColor(colorA);
let colorB = Color(uiColor: uiColorA);`, you will see that `colorB != Color.blue`
Question is: why is it a problem? It's not the same constant, but the same color...

Comment: @flatasearth If they are the same color then `==` should return true. `===` would be false but why is `==` false if they are the same?

Comment: @flatasearth makes sense. The reason it's a problem is because I need to be able to match the saved color to it's original color so it can remain selected inf the UI for a palette of colors.

Comment: I fixed this by using UIColor everywhere. e.g store as UIColor without conversion. Check for equality as UIColors and only convert to Color when SwiftUI needs it.

Comment: @HangarRash too long to have this discussion here, but main thing to remember is that both Color and UIColor are floating point numbers under the hood.

Comment: @Kex definitely a good solution at least until Apple migrates away from any ObjC serialization (will that ever happen?)

Comment: @flatasearth haha who knows. This is my first time diving into core data and it feels like an antique, yet has really cool features like requiring almost zero work to sync with iCloud. It's confusing.